# Angular Material datepicker incorrect default date

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I am using Material datepicker and datepicker's date always default to 1/1/1 with `MatNativeDateModule` and 1/1/0001 with `MatMomentDateModule`. Even on setting the date programattically date defaults to 1/1/1.

I am using reactive forms. When I don't provide `formControlName`, date defaults to current date which is the desired behavior but when I provide `formControlName` it shows incorrect date.

I am using Angular version 12 with Angular Material version 12.2.5. I am simply importing `MatDatepickerModule`, `MatNativeDateModule` and `MatMomentDateModule` in my main module and in html everything is copied from angular documentation.
Below is my code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="startDate" [matDatepicker]="picker1">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More code in the question would be nice, but if I understand you correctly..

Change `formControlName="startDate"` to `[formControl]="startDate"`
and ensure you have set the formControl in the component.

E.g:

```js
startDate = new FormControl(new Date(2021, 1, 1));
```

If it's part of a FormGroup, formControlName should be used. Then in the .ts,

```js
yourGroup = new FormGroup({
  startDate = new FormControl(new Date(2021, 1, 1));
});
```

More on how to use new Date() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)